# ibswiftCore.dylib: Permission denied, failed to run on simulator/device

Tags: xcode, swift3

After installing xcode8 I get the following 'compiling swift standard libraries' error:

Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '1C2273B489890D7C4407493EB7A4A0BC7E7D38FF' '--verbose' '-D' 'DEBUG' '/Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: Permission denied
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '1C2273B489890D7C4407493EB7A4A0BC7E7D38FF' '--verbose' '-D' 'DEBUG' '/Users/kamend/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Evento-hhvrbzmhxucgladakdcphldjxugg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UTA.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}

Other projects runs just fine, any suggestions?

Update: the project does not run on another computer also

Comment: Have you tried to remove derived data ?

Comment: @azimov yes, I even tried to compile it on another computer - no luck. I will try with xcode 7.3 today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it :)
Not sure why I had 'Other code signing flags' set to "-D DEBUG".
Removing it solved the problem